# How do I run the levene test correctly, in R?

Tags: r, warnings, p-value

I tried to run the levene Test with the data below:in the picture

[tha data I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua6l3.png)

I used this code: leveneTest(Daten$Quantity,Daten$Hightclass)

But I got this output:

Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
Df F value Pr(>F)
group  3     NaN    NaN
0
Warning message:
In leveneTest.default(Daten$Anzahl, Daten$Hohe) :
Daten$Hohe coerced to factor.

Does someone know what that means? Is there a problem with my data? Is there no p-Value?

Thank you all so much in advance!

Comment: Homogeneity is only assessed with numbers. If you wanted to assess the bivariate or multivariate variance, you can, but you would need (at a minimum) multiple values for each category. For anything other than univariate assessment, I would encourage you to look at the residuals (homoskedasticity). The reason you are getting NA is that you are not working with data appropriate for this test. If you want to adjust your question, make sure to use a reproducible example. It will get you answers a lot faster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example